# Is it possible for the Cauchy product of the two series to converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n,b_n > 0, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n < \infty, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n = \infty$. Is it possible for the Cauchy product of the two series to converge?

Comment: In general, in particular, if $a_n,b_n\ge0$, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, under the given assumptions, the Cauchy product always diverges. We have

$$c_n = \sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} a_k b_{n-k} \geqslant a_1\cdot b_{n-1}$$

for all $n\geqslant 2$, so

$$\sum_{n = 2}^N c_n \geqslant a_1\sum_{m = 1}^{N-1} b_m \to +\infty.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $a_n={1\over{n^3}}$, $b_n=n$

Comment: The Cauchy product is the series with general term $(c_n)_{n\geq1}$ where, for $n\geq1$, $c_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k b_{n-k}$. In this case, $c_n=n\sum_{k=1}^n1/k^3-\sum_{k=1}^n1/k^2\underset{n\to+\infty}\to+\infty$ and clearly the series $\sum_n c_n$ diverges.

Comment: You thought of the termwise product of the series, not the Cauchy product.